# Client side spam handling solution for ubuntu linux/thunderbird user?

Tags: email, thunderbird, spam-prevention

I'm using Mozilla Thunderbird 2.0 on Ubuntu Linux 9.04, and quite frankly, the junk mail detection isn't what it used to be.  Frankly, it now sucks.

I have control over my mail server, but before I go playing around there, I was wondering whether there's a good client side solution for despamming my email, such as a thunderbird plugin or integration with a better spam detection?

I connect to my mail server via imaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using [POPFile](http://getpopfile.org) on Windows for years and I love it.  They also have a cross-platform version that "...can be used on any platform (including Windows) where  Perl and the necessary modules are installed."